# ASP.NET MVC view models from key / value pairs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How would could I represent a key / value pair as an ASP.NET MVC model? My form data is not backed by a strongly typed model.

My first solution was to design my form using Razor and use some extension methods to get the FormElement values.

```
@model IEnumerable<FormElementKeyValues>

@Html.TextBox(Model.GenerateID("Email"), Model.GetFormElementValue("Email"))<br />
```

This works but it becomes messy when I want to process data from a POST. I have no model so I am forced to fall back to using a FormCollection which means I lose the benefit of strongly typed model and validation.

A second solution (I haven't tried this yet) would be to create my individual form models and decorate the properties with custom attributes that help me get access to the key / value pairs.

```
public SimpleFormModel {

    [FormElement("Fullname")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string Fullname { get; set; }

    [FormElement("Email")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [DisplayName("E-mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public ComplexFormModel {

    [FormElement("Firstname")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [FormElement("Surname")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [FormElement("Email")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [DisplayName("E-mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

This would allow me to use a strongly-typed model within my view along with the standard Razor Html Helpers.

```
<div class="editor-field">
  @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Firstname))
  @(Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Firstname))
  @(Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Firstname))
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're way over complicating this task...

Models are there for you to both render, and consume from your Razor views...

So for instance, say I had a website selling tickets to festivals, and I have a order form I want to make reusable across all the different events I'm selling tickets for and that I wanted to pre populate the name of the event in that form... this is how you would do it...

First of all you need a model,

```
public class RegistrationViewModel {
    [Display(Name = "Event")]
    public string EventName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Next let's imagine we have a `Events` Controller with an Action called `Register`

```
public class Events : Controller 
{
    public ActionResult Register(int id)
    {
        Event event = DbSource.FindEventById(id);

        RegistrationViewModel model = new RegistrationViewModel 
        {
            EventName = event.Name
        }

        return this.View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegistrationViewModel model)
    {
        if( ! ModelState.IsValid ) 
        {
            return this.View(model);
        }

        // ship the tickets, return thank you view, etc...
    }
}
```

And finally our view....

```
@model RegistrationViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Events")
{
    <div>
        @(Html.AntiForgeryToken())

        @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.EventName))
        @(Html.ValueFor(model => model.EventName))

        @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName))
        @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName))
        @(Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName))

        @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName))
        @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName))
        @(Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName))
    </div>
}
```

I've written this on the fly so I don't know if it will compile as is, but what I've shown you is basically all there is to it...

Comment: This is of course the ideal solution. I am going on the assumption that you have an Event table in your database and the EventModel is a 1:1 representation of that.

My forms do not have database models behind them. I have 2 tables FormElement and FormValue (I know this is a terrible design but it is a legacy system from 2007 that handles 500,000 transactions per year so I can't go changing this just like that :().

Comment: @flip while a DB that looks like that may not be ideal, it sounds like you have a perfect scenario for having a View Model which translates to your Data Model. I know that going straight from Data Model to the View is nice, but sometimes you can't help it, like in the case of a goofy DB schema (sounds like a tdwtf submission), or interacting with a service. Personally I prefer to use a View Model because it decouples the UI from the DB design.

Comment: @CodeMonkey1313 indeed, my first solution is a workable solution until I can move to a complete view / model architecture.

Comment: What I've presented above would not be a model of your database, the event would be in an `Events` table, and the first name and last name would be columns of a `Customers` table, the above `RegistrationViewModel` will later be converted to our business mode... Use a POCO generator to create your domain models since you already have a database